# Failing to suspend, AMD GPU just goes black

Tags: suspend, amd-graphics, amdgpu

After a recent update on 21.10 (not sure if that's what caused it, best guess, it's been working fine until a few days ago, seemingly right after an update), suspend doesn't work. Monitors go dark, and that's it. Can't even recover without a reboot.

Dmesg gives:

```
[13659.802135] Freezing user space processes ... 
[13679.807380] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.005 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[13679.807401] task:Xorg            state:D stack:    0 pid: 1961 ppid:  1952 flags:0x00400004
[13679.807406] Call Trace:
[13679.807408]  <TASK>
[13679.807412]  __schedule+0x268/0x680
[13679.807420]  schedule+0x4f/0xc0
[13679.807423]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
[13679.807426]  __mutex_lock.constprop.0+0x31e/0x4e0
[13679.807433]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[13679.807436]  mutex_lock+0x34/0x40
[13679.807439]  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail+0x53b/0x1240 [amdgpu]
[13679.807679]  ? enqueue_task_fair+0x153/0x5c0
[13679.807683]  ? __find_get_block+0x31/0x90
[13679.807688]  ? __cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[13679.807690]  ? page_counter_cancel+0x2c/0x60
[13679.807694]  ? page_counter_uncharge+0x22/0x40
[13679.807697]  ? drain_stock+0x65/0xb0
[13679.807699]  ? page_counter_cancel+0x2c/0x60
[13679.807702]  ? drm_atomic_helper_check_planes+0x161/0x200 [drm_kms_helper]
[13679.807721]  ? __cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[13679.807724]  ? __wait_for_common+0x3d/0x150
[13679.807727]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xfb/0x240
[13679.807730]  ? __cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[13679.807734]  ? wait_for_completion_timeout+0x1d/0x20
[13679.807737]  commit_tail+0x99/0x130 [drm_kms_helper]
[13679.807753]  drm_atomic_helper_commit+0x123/0x150 [drm_kms_helper]
[13679.807769]  drm_atomic_commit+0x4a/0x50 [drm]
[13679.807801]  drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x7c/0xc0 [drm_kms_helper]
[13679.807817]  drm_mode_setcrtc+0x1f9/0x7b0 [drm]
[13679.807844]  ? drm_mode_getcrtc+0x180/0x180 [drm]
[13679.807869]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xae/0xf0 [drm]
[13679.807895]  drm_ioctl+0x247/0x460 [drm]
[13679.807920]  ? drm_mode_getcrtc+0x180/0x180 [drm]
[13679.807946]  amdgpu_drm_ioctl+0x4e/0x80 [amdgpu]
[13679.808118]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x91/0xc0
[13679.808122]  do_syscall_64+0x61/0xb0
[13679.808125]  ? fput+0x13/0x20
[13679.808128]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x87/0xb0
[13679.808131]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
[13679.808133]  ? __x64_sys_write+0x19/0x20
[13679.808135]  ? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
[13679.808137]  ? sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x4e/0x90
[13679.808140]  ? asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0xa/0x20
[13679.808143]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
[13679.808145] RIP: 0033:0x7f84ca569a2b
[13679.808148] RSP: 002b:00007ffd9041f368 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[13679.808151] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffd9041f3a0 RCX: 00007f84ca569a2b
[13679.808153] RDX: 00007ffd9041f3a0 RSI: 00000000c06864a2 RDI: 000000000000000f
[13679.808154] RBP: 00000000c06864a2 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[13679.808156] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000563842ffbd30
[13679.808157] R13: 000000000000000f R14: 00005638421d45e0 R15: 00005638439ad6f0
[13679.808159]  </TASK>

[13679.808243] OOM killer enabled.
[13679.808244] Restarting tasks ... done.
```

GPU is:

```
0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 14 [Radeon Pro W5500]
```

Any idea how to troubleshoot would be helpful, Google didn't turn anything up that I could find after some extensive searching.

Comment: At the end there, it says `OOM killer enabled.`. The OOM killer kills processes when you're out of memory. How much RAM do you have, and how much swap do you have?

Comment: Currently using 20.2/62.7 Gig memory and no swap. Don't think memory is an issue, happens immediately after booting if I try to suspend.